# Is it possible to check if a function has a decorator from a class attribute in DRF and Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently thinking of how to implement permissions in my Django application using DRF. My idea is to have several generic classes that inherit `BasePermission` and to define those classes in the view, ex:

```
class ExampleView(ModelViewSet):
   permission_classes = (ExamplePermissionClass,)
```

However, this might not suffice for some views that I have i.e. I might declare a generic class on the whole view but I might also want one `@action` to use different permissions. For this, I though of making decorator permissions which would check permissions on a per method basis. However, I do think that `permission_classes` are executed first and this won't work. Is there a way arround this?

Example:

```
class ExampleView(ModelViewSet):
   permission_classes = (ExamplePermissionClass,)
   
   @permissions(PermissionName etc...)
   @action(...)
   def example_action
```

How can I circumvent the permission class and only check the decorator here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_permissions` method to configure different permissions for different actions:

```py
def get_permissions(self):
    if self.action == "example_action":
        return (ExamplePermissionClass1, ExamplePermissionClass2)
    else:
        return self.permission_classes   # Default value
```

Take a look a [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#overview-of-access-restriction-methods) section of the documentation for more info.